# How to avoid scientific notation in Python?

Tags: java, python

I'm using an API that passes data from Python to Java. My issue is the Java does not like e notation. I get an illegal character exception. So I need to format my input such that there is no e in it. I'm using Python 2.7; if a newer version would help I could move up.

Decimal doesn't work (w=1e-8, e = w*100000000):

> >>>Decimal(e)/Decimal(1)
>
> Decimal('1')
>
> >>>Decimal(e)/Decimal(100000000)
>
> Decimal('1E-8')
>
> >>>Decimal(w)/Decimal(1)
>
> Decimal('1.000000000E-8')

String formatting doesn't work:

> >>>print "%.16f" % w
>
> 0.0000000100000000
>
> >>>s = "%.16f" % w
>
> >>>Decimal(s)
>
> Decimal('1.00000000E-8')

Float doesn't work; is there a way? I don't have access to the Java code so I can't cast it on that side. Thanks!

Comment: Also: with `s = "%.16f" % w`, `s` will be what you want, with some trailing zeroes.

Comment: Yep, looks like the extra step of converting to decimal is what messed me up. Thanks!